# Can't map a JSON sub entity in Grails

Tags: json, grails, mapping

I am writing a Grails application that sends and receives everything in JSON format. 
I am trying to map the below JSON string sent as a request parameter to the below assessment object:

JSON String:

```
{
"assessment_name": "Structured Clinical Assessment",
"consultant": {
    "class": "ie.rcsi.Consultant",
    "id": 1,
    "consultant_email": "jon.doe@madeup.ie",
    "consultant_name": "Jon Doe",
    "dateCreated": "2013-12-17T17:07:03Z",
    "hospitals": [],
    "imc": "12345678910"
},
  "consultantId": 1,
  "notes": " "
}


class Assessment {

    String assessment_name
    static belongsTo = [consultant: Consultant]

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
        lazy: false
    }
}

class Consultant {
    String consultant_name
    String consultant_email
    String imc
    Date dateCreated

    static constraints = {
        consultant_name blank: false, unique: false
        consultant_email blank: true, unique: true
        imc blank: true, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't map to the sub-entity consultant. I thought that putting the property `"class": "ie.rcsi.Consultant"` (for example) would get it to map automatically. 
Does anybody know how I can do this, or of a plugin in Grails that will do this?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Test it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @LutzHorn The json is vallid .I cheked on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Witch version of Grails are you using? I know that 2.3.x have better support for this. Also you should consider using naming conventions: `consultantName` instead of `consultant_name`.

Comment: Look into objectMarshallers. That will allow you to customize the JSON exactly how you want it.

Comment: I read the question wrong. objectMarshallers will only help with outputting JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you use at least Grails 2.3.

This may affect you: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9220